# How did you know I wrote/had written it

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple

In a classroom, one student (A) to another (B):

A: You wrote it on the board, right?

B1: I'm surprised! How did you know I **wrote** it.

B2: I'm surprised! How did you know I **had written** it.

What's the difference between B1 and B2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple past vs Perfect Past](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31718/simple-past-vs-perfect-past)

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, and both are perfectly idiomatic. For most purposes, all you need to know is ***Simplest is best.*** But native Anglophones will sometimes choose to use the perfect in this exact context because they're particularly interested in *what the addressee thought / knew **at the time when they first encountered the "evidence"***. But that *wouldn't* usually be the case. Usually, the speaker doesn't particularly care about that level of "temporal precision" - all he wants to know is how the addressee came to his conclusion, *whenever he did so*.

Answer (score 1):

B1: I'm surprised! How did you know I wrote it?

B2: I'm surprised! How did you know I had written it?

The difference in meaning is in **the wider context** and not grammar  here. If one thing precedes another and it is important or meaningful in a situation, we use the past perfect.

How *did you know* **I had written it** before you arrived? It was only when you arrived that you found out.